# How to transform a generator into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, generator, pyodbc

I'm importing some data from an SQL Server and transforming them into dataframes with pandas as it follows:

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;UID=user;PWD=password')
DF = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM file", cnxn, chunksize = 20000)
```

It was working fine, until I had to work with a file that is really huge. In order to preserve memory, the read_sql_query function stopped returning me an dataframe object and began to return an generator object.

The problem is that I have to create new files merging the dataframe objects and the generators. I could transform the generator into a dataframe packing the chunks into a list and then concatenating them into a dataframe, like

```py
list_of_chunks = []
for chunk in generator:
    list_of_chunks.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(list_of_chunks)
```

which works fine, but consumes too much memory. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM file", cnxn, chunksize=1000000)])
`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It returned me the error "_get_axis() missing 1 required positional argument: 'axis'". I tried to specify an axis in the pd.concat function, but didn't worked. Also, the script ran for like 30s and the memory usage was really huge.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "which works fine, but consumes too much memory" is really the best option. You might want to try distributed computing with dask instead.